# One IP address, Two Websites, on Two Machines - Need details

Tags: server, apache2, proxy, port-forwarding

This question has already been posted by another user but a detailed answer was not given..
Here is the link to the original question - [One IP address, Two Websites, on Two Machines](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41995/one-ip-address-two-websites-on-two-machines)

I have two machines each with apache2 installed and static ip addresses.

**Server 1**

```
example.com
static ip = 192.168.0.6
apache2 running on ports 80 and 443 fine
ufw and router firewall are open on ports 80 and 443 as well
```

**Server 2**

```
domain name = myhost01.example.com 
static ip = 192.168.0.7
apache2 running on 8080(HTTP) and 8443(HTTPS) 
ufw and router firewall are open on ports 8080 and 8443
```

When I go to {http)www.example.com or (https)www.example.com - I correctly receive the web content for server 1

When I go to myhost01.example.com:8080 or myhost01.example.com:8443 - I correctly receive the web content for server 2

I would like to reverse proxy server 2 so when a user goes to http:// myhost01 .example.com/ they receive the content for http:// myhost01. example.com:8080/, basically hiding the port number.  Currently, I get an "unable to connect/webpage not found" error, when i try to access myhost01(dot)example(dot)com

In the Virtual Host file for example.com, I used the following:

```
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass / http://myhost01. example.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://myhost01 .example.com:8080/
```

Both proxy and proxy_http modules are enabled in apache2

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

**P.S. - Spaces were added to the urls because I do not have enough reputation points to post more than two urls.**

** **UPDATE** - See notes below

**Server1 - example.com - VHOST FILE**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin myadm@example.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /myweb/cmweb/apache/http

#ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://myhost01.example.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://myhost01.example.com:8080/

        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /myweb/cmweb/apache/http/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all

        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

Tried Proxy with 192.168.0.7 replacing myhost01(dot)example(dot)com to no avail

**Server2 - myhost01(dot)example(dot)com VHOST File**

```
 <VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerAdmin mwdhost@example.com
    ServerName myhost01.example.com
    ServerAlias myhost01 myhost01.example.com

    DocumentRoot /mwdhost/cmweb/apache/http

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /mwdhost/cmweb/apache/http/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

myhost01 has been added to A Record of Domain Registrant
can do an NSLOOKUP and get correct external ip address for myhost01.example.com

Here below is the Apache Error.log for server1 - Might be a clue to my problems???

```
Sun Feb 02 18:24:52 2014] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 54.43.138.12:8080 (myhost01.example.com) failed
[Sun Feb 02 18:24:52 2014] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (myhost01.example.com)
[Sun Feb 02 18:24:53 2014] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (myhost01.example.com) 
[Mon Feb 03 07:33:54 2014] [warn] Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)
```

Comment: Can you post the full configuration of your vhosts? Seen http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestions:

**Checked that server1(example.com) can lookup and get a correct dns record for `myhost01.example.com`?**

**Do your servers have one public IP each and a internal one each? Or is it like the linked question that you have one IP?**

*Do i smell a cheap router that have one IP, runs nat and port forwarding on the mentioned ports?*

- It is often so with cheap routers that they have issues with combining nat and portforwarding using external addresses to reach other internal machines. Some also fail this on purpose as it is bad practice to send all your internal load thought your gateway/nat router.

*Both dns records (myhost1.example.com and example.com) points to the same public IP?*

- yes, and that is intentional and correct, but what happens?

  - When the Apache instance wanna lookup where to do the proxy connection it will be told the external IP of `myhost01.example.com` that is pointing back to the router that might fail the connection. Lets assume it does.

*We found one possible error, how do we work around it?*

- As the external IP from the dns will not help server1 to find the local IP to go over the local network do we need a way to do it, luckily does it exist many ways to Rome.

  - One way would be to use the local IP of server2 in the ProxyPass.
  - Another way would be to simply override your dns answers. That can be done on server1 that serves as the proxy. Edit the file `/etc/hosts`. Some more info about the [hosts file can you read here.](http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap9sec95.html)
  - A 3rd way would be to make extra dns records for your local servers. Eg a entry named eg. local2.example.com pointing to `192.168.0.7`.

*Note.* If you wondered, it is fully possible to have more public IP's and run them on a little subnet eg. that will also be serving as the interconnection. Thought it is not very recommended to do so.

**Disclaimer**

This answer is based on an experienced guess, as complete configuration, Apache logs and errors are lacking from the answer. Feel free to improve.

Comment: Thanks Anders -- ADDED server2 internal ip address (192.168.0.7) to hosts file (/etc/hosts) of server1 so it reads 
192.168.0.6  www.example.com
192.168.0.6  example.com
192.168.0.7  myhost01.example.com
 and rebooted machine

.... Did not fix

Comment: Will post error logs after work today :)

Comment: @Cmweb `Sun Feb 02 18:24:52 2014] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 54.43.138.12:8080 (myhost01.example.com) failed` Is exactly what i described above unless you changed the 192.168.0.7 to 54.43.138.12 to hide your servers internal ip. Your proxy is failing to establish a connection and it seems for me that it is still trying to use the external ip, and not the local network.

Comment: @Cmweb Can you do eg. a ping from server one to `myhost01.example.com` does it still try to use the external ip? If yes, check that your changes to the hosts file is still there. 2nd. can you add the output of this command `cat /etc/nsswitch.conf | grep hos` , done on server1.

Comment: WOW ..something so simple can cause such big problems.  I think I fixed it ...on server2 I forgot to put the internal ip of server1 so each time it would look for the external ip address and fail. ...wow that was strange ...rebooted and was able to load the "nginx" welcome page but then I removed nginx because I am using apache2 and now nothing loads again?

Comment: It worked ...I think the combination of using the internal ip in the Pass config and add the internal ip of both servers to the hosts file on both servers did the trick.  I also did a "hard server reboot"   Thanks again for the assist Anders.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems like overkill.

All modern web servers will allow you to bind multiple web sites to a single ip address and port.  This is done by configuring the host header name for the respective sites.

Additionally, you can point multiple SSL sites to the same ip address and port (443 or whatever) by the use of SNI.  Older browsers don't support SNI, but that might not be a concern for you.

Hooking one of the sites to port 8080 and then wiring a proxy over it is the long way, unless there's an explicit need for port 8080 to be exposed to a client somehow.

Being the busy guy that I am, I don't spend a lot of time on Apache configuration unless I absolutely need to.  Otherwise, I use Virtualmin (http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html) and it handles 85% of the dirty work for such  configuration.

Comment: Codenoire...I will do some research on SNI ..It is new to me. Also, I thought support for webmin - at least for Linux/Ubuntu had died.  Will look into the Vitualmin option or others like it.  Thanks!